# RMarkdown produce text based on a calculated value

Tags: r

I am trying to create an RMarkdown report that pulls the last and second to last values of a column, calculates the percent change between the two, and then produces text based on the percent change to say whether it is an increase or decrease from the previous week.

Example data for df "dataset"

```
week  num_people  num_houses
30    1200        400
31    1300        410
32    1400        310
33    1350        325
34    1200        400
```

Defining values for this week and last week

```
this_week <- tail(dataset$week, n=1)
last_week <- head(tail(dataset$week, n=2),1)
```

Defining values for num_people column for this week and last week

```
this_week_people <- tail(dataset$num_people, n=1)
last_week_people <- head(tail(dataset$num_people, n=2),1)
```

Calculating percent change between this week and last week

```
pct_change_people <- round(((this_week_people - last_week_people)/last_week_people*100), digits = 1)
```

So in this case desired output would be text that says "There was a decrease of 11.1% from Week 34 to Week 33"

What I have so far is:

```
There was a ??? of `r pct_change_people`% from `r last_week` to `r this_week`.
```

How do I get the correct text for the ??? part?

Comment: It does thank you!